# Any close event of react-native modal when sliding down

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

Any event on closing react-native modal sliding it down without using any button inside the modal (onDismiss didn't work)?
Talking about this modal https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug that may be fixed in the next release.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26892

A workaround until then (using the example in the documentation):

```js
setModalVisible = visible => {
    // Assuming that the button who's calling this method is behind the modal, before clicking it, first set modal to visible false, then set the state from the button `visible` or not.
    this.setState({modalVisible: false});
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
    });
  };
```